# Trouble identifying mixed content on website

Tags: ssl, joomla3.0

I have tried whynopadlock and then view source scanning for anything with a http absolute address but am completely stuck on identifying where the problem is and could use someones help. It must be a script or something.

The page in question is https://www.uniqbuy.co.uk/orders/list.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

whynopadlock.com reports:

> A file with an insecure url of "http://www.uniqbuy.co.uk/" was loaded
>   on line: 845 of https://www.uniqbuy.co.uk/orders/list.html.

which looks like it refers to this:

```
<img src="/images/comodo_secure_seal_76x26_transp.png" alt="" />
```

You could try amending your code to this:

```
<img src="https://www.uniqbuy.co.uk/images/comodo_secure_seal_76x26_transp.png" alt="" />
```

Forcing https by adding the following or similar lines to your .htaccess file might be a better solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but it's not that image causing the error. I could force https on all pages but it isn't really what I want to do. The Firefox and Chrome console doesn't give any useful information either.

Comment: Ok, you might want to add what you have already tried to your question.